# scopes in azure AD different from scopes in application (Microsoft Graph Api)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to access files in `OneDrive` using `Microsoft Graph` api,

In my `Azure AD` I gave the following permissions:[image]

And in my application I have the following code:
[image]

However when I run the application it's giving me the following error:

`Error getting access token: AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. One or more scopes in 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access profile openid' are not compatible with each other.`
Even tho I didn't give `offline_access profile openid` permissions anywhere else.

Even if I change `_scopes` to `private string[] _scopes = new string[4]{"User.Read","Files.ReadWriteAll.All","Files.Read","Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder"}` I would still get the same error but `"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"` would be replaced with the above values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you provide, the scope you use is not right. It should be `private string[] _scopes = new string[4]{"User.Read","Files.ReadWrite.All","Files.Read","Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder"}`.

For example

1. Regaister Azure AD application
2. Enable device code flow
   [image]
3. Code

```
            var client = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("")
                .WithAuthority( AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMyOrg)
                .WithTenantId("consumers")
                .Build();

            var scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Files.ReadWrite.All" , "Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder", "Files.Read" };
           await  client.AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode(scopes, deviceCodeResult =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(deviceCodeResult.Message);
                return Task.FromResult(0);

            }).ExecuteAsync();
```

[image]